# How to --> Offer a coupon for a Tweet

Tags: php, twitter

I've seen recently a few times when companies offer either a download link or a coupon code for people that will tweet about it. It is all automated and I would like to do something like this but I'm not quite clear on the process.

Usually you go to a page with a link. You click on a link and it asks if you would give permission for some Tweeter app to connect to your profile. You grant permission and it brings up a pre-composed twitter message, something like: "I just got a coupon to try out..." Once the twitter message is sent, you are re-directed to a page where you find your coupon code.

I use PHP and can write whatever is needed to get this done.

Anyone knows how it is all done?

---

Update:

OK, I downloaded http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/still not clear what to do next.

I am trying to figure out startuing with this page: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo#Two-legged_OAuth

The way I understand the process the following should take place in this order:

1. I need a link somewhere on my site that will have an offer: "Send a Twit and receive a coupon", right?
2. Once they click on the offer link, how do I populate a message into their twitter update window: "Trying out this tool for free: http"//mylink.com"?
3. Once they submit Twitter post, I suppose I will have some settings that will redirect back to my site to a page with a coupon.

---

UPDATE: switched to [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/), but still need help...

Comment: *"I use PHP and can write whatever is needed to get this done."* - Go for it: Install one of the many [twitter PHP APIs](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php), offer your users to use it with their credential with some little PHP script. Post tweets for them within that little PHP script, redirect them on success via sending the location header to your coupon script. Done.

Comment: That "little PHP script"... I'd love to see an example of that. What is it suppose to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, you have to create an app that uses the OAuth API to connect to twitter and post a tweet. This takes several steps (assuming you've registered your application with Twitter, giving you a key and secret):

1. Build TwitterOAuth object using client credentials.
2. Request temporary credentials from Twitter.
3. Build authorize URL for Twitter.
4. Redirect user to authorize URL.
5. User authorizes access and returns from Twitter.
6. Rebuild TwitterOAuth object with client credentials and temporary credentials.
7. Query Twitter API.

Using [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/), it would look something like this:

```
<?php
  require_once 'TwitterOAuth.php';
  define('THIS', 'http://example.org/tweet.php'); // Absolute URI to script

  if(isset($_GET['callback']) {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                      $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
    $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Coupon message'));
    header('Location: coupon.php'); // Supplies user with coupon
  } else {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth('key', 'secret'); // Key & secret from Twitter
    $temporary_credentials = $connection->getRequestToken(THIS.'?');
    $redirect_url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($temporary_credentials, FALSE);
    header('Location: '.$redirect_url.'&callback');
  }
?>
```

(Note that the above code is untested; read the documentation of TwitterOAuth before doing things yourself.)

Comment: I already have an app setup with the Twitter for this site, can I use it or do I need to setup a new one?

Comment: @santa: You should be able to use the same key/secret pair here.

Comment: OK, I followed documentation and now I have a start page, where a user can click on a "Login w/ Twitter" button, redirected to Twitter. After successful login there, they are redirected back to my redirect.php page which checks for successful login and if true -- sends them to a specified page. At which point I get them to twit and upon successful post of the twit redirect them back to coupon code page? Still kinda unclear on the process.

Comment: @santa: That's pretty much exactly how it goes.

Comment: I understand, but I am not looking for them to access my page after successful login on Twitter. I need them to twit the offer and then get redirected to a coupon. How do I do that? I feel like I am 75% there but not sure what the remaining 25% is.

Comment: @santa: After they've been redirected back to your site and you've checked that they are logged in, use the OAuth credentials to post a message on their Twitter account (this is done programmatically). When this has been done, redirect them to a coupon.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that programmatically. Don't they need to see a message and click "Tweet" button? Is there an example anywhere that I can take a look at?

Comment: @santa: As far as i understand, they don't. The code provided in my answer (the `if(isset($_GET['callback'])` part) should be all you need.

Comment: @santa let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1423/discussion-between-you-and-santa)

Answer (score 3):

For the more lazy of us ;) [This](http://www.paywithatweet.com/sell.php) makes a button to [pay with a tweet](http://www.paywithatweet.com/) (like so [image]) and links to an URL of your choice afterwards. I guess you could reach most off your goals with this *(though coupon codes that are personal might be tricky)*.

Comment: This is cool! I suppose, until I figure out how to make my code work I'll opt in for this app.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Abraham's Twitter OAuth Library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth), I would suggest it as it makes the OAuth flow incredibly easy.

What you'll want to do is make a link like "Tweet about this to get a free download" or whatever. That link will redirect them to authorize your Twitter Application, when the callback comes back to your site, you request an Access Token and save it. This page should have a text box pre-populated with your message that posts to your site with the message that they want to send. You'll do an API call to post the message with the access token you received. Once you make the call and post the tweet, show them the page for the download.

Take a look at the [TwitterOAuth Library Documentation](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION) as it has detailed examples on how to use the library to make the calls you're looking for.

Comment: I have used that library, but still struggle with getting a tweet posted.

Answer (score 0):

A little PHP script and what it does:

```
// php.ini::session.auto_start=1
include('commands.php');
$command = get_command_from_request();
switch($command) {
  case 'tweet': 
      command_tweet(); break;
  case 'redirect':
      command_redirect(); break;
  default:
    command_default();
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to implement the mapping of a command to the request yourself (implementation of `get_command_from_request`), as well for the concrete commands.

Tweeting depends on the API you use. Any of the many APIs in question has this as an example.

Next to that you need to build a HTML form to gather the data you need to tweet (the API keys and such). If you have no clue how data goes into your script, checkout the [PHP manual about forms](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP%20manual%20about%20forms&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

So let's assume the `command_default` to display the form as well as the it's verification inside `command_tweet` and the `get_command_from_request` is done now. The rest is doing the redirect to your secret coupon script.

As you have not shared much about your secret coupon script, a redirect is probably enough. A nice function for doing a HTTP redirect in PHP is [`http_redirect()`](http://php.net/function.http-redirect).

Comment: I've ended-up implementing TwitterOAuth, and although everything seem to work I don't see a message posted.